# Is it safe to enter your credentials on eBuddy for iPhone?

Tags: security, password

I'm hesitant in using it, as it asks for all your passwords for your messaging programs.

What is their privacy policy? Has anyone ever had problems with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the App Store approval checks, Apple analyzes all network data for unnecessary or malicious connectivity, meaning if it's on the App Store, it's not sending your data back to the authors.

Comment: I'm curious, they don't do it in Android Market?

Comment: Android Market is 100% open. It's good and bad, and this is a bad.

Comment: "if it's on the App Store, it's not sending your data back to the authors." This is 100% false. Data goes back to the author and the AdNetworks they choose to bundle into the app (even if it doesn't display ads) for statistics purposes. And no, you will not necessarily be prompted for anything.

Comment: @VxJasonxV, I meant his login information.

Comment: How do you know this? Because you like Apple products, and nothing you like could be bad?  Answer below describes clearly the danger with this sketch machine of a program. Their own words are the rope they should hang by.

Answer (score 0):

Give away your password?

What's their liability? ( none )

What's their privacy policy ( you'll never know when it gets stolen )

What do you get in return?  ( A chat client like adium. Adium!)

http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/blogs/ybenjamin/detail?entry_id=46417

Ebuddy, bottom of that page is used as an example.

I'd say no:  Try

[Remodium](http://remodium.com/)

or if you have to have that sort of service, make a throwaway acct like insecure@gmail.com or whoknowswhothisis@hotmail.com.